# Tab for older open questions to be answered

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A tab for [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) questions exists.

I know the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) tab does exactly this, but how about a tab for (older) open questions? For example, I look back at questions from a year ago and there are open questions that have not been given a comprehensive answer (or, I'm sure in most cases, simply have not been accepted by the OP).

Would it be a good idea to bring attention to open questions that were asked over a month/three months/six months/one year ago that have answers but no accepted answers?

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319944/http-post-to-facebook-graph-api-for-wall-post-throwing-oauthexception) to illustrate my point. A user downvoted the question because it's "wasting space and people's time" since the OP didn't answer/accept an answer, but what if the the OP's question was not fully answered?